# SplunkForwarder in Docker container does not take authentication from CLI

Tags: docker, splunk

I am trying to run Splunk in docker container and do not want to manually type username and password. So, I am using CLI command in a script: 
/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk --accept-license --answer-yes --no-prompt --auth admin: start

This throws me error stating: 
Command error: The subcommand 'admin:' is not valid for command '-auth'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not checked, but in entrypoint.sh for splunk image I used one dash for the `auth` to make it work, so `-auth admin:changeme` should have only one dash. See for example https://github.com/splunk/docker-splunk/blob/master/enterprise/entrypoint.sh

Btw, if you are using Splunk >=7.1, you will find an issue, that `admin:changeme` does not work anymore, so you need to seed a password https://www.outcoldsolutions.com/blog/2018-04-25-docker-splunk-7-1-0/

Also, in your splunk command, I do not see a command. You give a lot of arguments, but there is no actionable command, like `start` or `add`.

If you are using an official image, you can give commands to the splunk by using environment variables, see https://github.com/splunk/docker-splunk/tree/master/enterprise

Comment: I am working on Splunk 7.1.2 and the -auth command shows 'bad option -a error'. I changed the command to:/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk start --accept-license --answer-yes --no-prompt --seed-passwd <password>      But, still I have to manually type the username and password after running the docker image. It works, but I want it to be taken from command line itself/script.

Comment: See in the blog post that I have posted - option 4, how you can seed the password using `user-seed.conf`, that way you will not need to mention a password in your configuration. But you will need to embed this conf file in your own image.

Comment: Even if I explicitly add configuration using user-seed.conf, docker container still asks for username and password while running it. Though, if I provide username and password like: docker run -it -h <hostname> --restart unless-stopped -e "SPLUNK_PASSWORD=<password>" <image_id> /bin/bash "script.sh". Then container does not asks me for password but still it requires me to enter username: admin(but not for password). Adding "SPLUNK_USER=admin" also does not help.

Comment: Not sure about your use case. If you want to run come CLI commands after you started Splunk - yes, it will ask you for a password. That is how Splunk behaves. If you want to configure Splunk on start - you can embed all configurations.

Comment: Resolved the issue by exporting username and password. Thanks @outcoldman